# Commerce equivalent of Signup, Pay Per Node, etc

Tags: 7, commerce

I had [previously asked](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/24575/is-drupal-appropriate-for-this-type-of-shopping-experience) for some information about specific e-commerce functions on D6, and was pointed to UberCart, along with Pay Per Node, Signup, and a few other modules. I've just learned that our hosting company has updated their php install so D7 is now supported.

Are there equivalents to those modules for D7? I know Commerce is the big one, but can it do pay-per-node type stuff (to support a print-on-demand fundraiser)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are a few links that might get you started.  Drupal commerce is a lot more powerful than Ubercart, because everything is fieldable you should be able to make your event signup product include any fields you wish to collect.  I'm not sure what you mean by print-on-demand fundraiser but hopefully this gets you heading in the right direction.

http://vimeo.com/31459435

http://mustardseedmedia.com/podcast/episode51

~Mark

Comment: The print-on-demand fundraiser was explained in the link I included in my OP. We are not dealing with inventory or stock - users can purchase items which are not created until the fundraiser is complete.

Comment: Thanks. I'll look at those. Unfortunately I'm having trouble getting the Commerce Kickstart profile to install...